# Python web scrape failing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hoping someone can help me through a webscrape.   It worked last year daily just fine, turned it off for winter and now something on the page has changed and it's no longer working.
I need to extract the Danger Rating codes for each station listed.  Last year, with BS looking for the "tr" tag it worked perfectly.  I'm stumped.

Here's the site for a sample region:  http://bcwildfire.ca/hprScripts/DgrCls/index.asp?Region=4

Here's my code up to where BS does its thing:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import string, datetime, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Fire Danger ratings by station start at index 4

class HTMLCleaner(HTMLParser):
    container = ""
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.container = self.container + "," + data
        return self.container

todayChk = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

##FireRegions = {'Prince George': '4', 'Northwest': '3', 'Cariboo': '7', 'Kamloops': '5', 'Southeast': '6'}
FireRegions = {'Prince George': '4'}

Regs = FireRegions.keys()
Reg = 0

while Reg < len(FireRegions):
    print Regs[Reg] + " Region"
    content = urlopen('http://bcwildfire.ca/hprScripts/DgrCls/index.asp?Region='+FireRegions[Regs[Reg]]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    PGStats = soup.body.find_all("tr")
    print PGStats
    Reg+=1
```

Thanks so much if you can offer a solution.

Comment: *"something on the page has changed"* - have you tried to figure out *what*?

Comment: I feel like something along the lines of `for reg in FireRegions.keys()` would look cleaner than the while loop followed by `FireRegions[Regs[Reg]]`

Comment: I'm not great with the BS module.  I've spent hours trying to get to the table of data I need with no luck.  The page looks pretty much the same as last year, couldn't see anything different.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion cricket.   I know my code isn't very efficient, I'll try to work your code into it, but that part works at the moment.  It's further down.  The "soup.body.find_all("tr") is no longer pulling what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is because of the extra `table` and `tr` elements on the page. You need to narrow down the search to a specific `table` with the stations and rating inside.

One option, since there are no `id` or `class` attributes which we can use to distinguish the desired table from others, would be to *find a table header by text* and then [go up to the parent `table` element](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent):

```
table = soup.find(text="[Dgr Rgn] Station").find_parent("table")
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    print(cells[0].get_text(), cells[1].get_text())
```

Prints:

```
(u'[1] BEAR LAKE', u'3')
(u'[1] BEDNESTI', u'3')
(u'[1] CHETWYND (EC)', u'4')
...
(u'[1] VALEMOUNT HUB', u'4')
(u'[1] VANDERHOOF HUB', u'4')
(u'[1] WONOWON', u'4')
```

Comment: Oh wow alecxe, that's exactly what I need, thanks very much!  I'll give that a try.